# Can't access $store when importing Vuex instance from an external file

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm creating a [counter using Vue & Vuex 2](https://github.com/guytepper/vuex-counter).
When trying to access the count property on the store object, using `this.$store.state.count`, I get an `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` error.

The error **doesn't** show up and everything works just fine when I'm creating the store instance inside `main.js`, instead of importing it.

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'Vuex'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'Vue'
import Vuex from 'Vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 1
  }
});
```

**Counter.vue**

```
export default {
  name: 'counter',
  template: `<span>{{ count }}</span>`,
  computed: {
    count () {
        return this.$store.state.count
    }
  },
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with the store import?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have imported vue differently:

```
import Vue from 'Vue'
```

within `store.js` and

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

within `main.js`

change your store.js import to match main.js to fix the issue, i.e.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'Vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 1
  }
});
```

you can also remove the Vuex import in main.js

Comment: On switching bundlers for a Vue project ran into a similar issue myself, was that the store's file was importing Vue's `vue/dist/vue` module 